# Cant figure out how to add user inputed names into array in java

Tags: java, arrays

//Ask user how many students and grades he wants to enter

```java
public void setup() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");

    numStudents = keyboard.nextInt();
}

public void setName(String someName) {

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter name of student # " + (i+1) + ": ");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nameRough = keyboard.nextLine();
        name = nameRough.trim();

      // i have to ask the user to enter the name int he for Last, first and         then rearrange it so this is what thats doing

        String firstName = name.substring(name.indexOf(",")+1);
        String lastName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(","));

        name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    //  name = nameList; 

        System.out.println("");

    // and then here is where i can't figure out how to add name to the           army at i 

        String[] namesList = new String[numStudents];

        nameList[i] = name;

    }
}
```

I want to just be able to add the names as the user enters them but after they are properly formatted. i only know how to add them to the string at the immediate time of them getting entered by the user

Comment: What do you mean by `but after they are properly formatted`?

Comment: Can you show your output/results from running what you have so far - will help others to help you.

Comment: You may want to look into the method `split(",")` for your names

Comment: But i want to prompted the user each time to enter the name

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Student.setName(Student.java:51)
 at Grades.main(Grades.java:29)

Comment: That's in code you haven't even given us... And is a problem with `Student` being `null`, not with the `setName` method

Comment: how is student null? I'm trying to add the names here

Comment: this is the line its referring to:  nick.setName(" name 1");

Comment: You haven't shown us that line in your original code... A null pointer exception suggests that `nick` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you need to declare `namesList` *outside* the loop:

```
public void setup() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");

    numStudents = keyboard.nextInt();
}

public void setName(String someName) {

    String[] nameList = new String[numStudents]; //out here

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter name of student # " + (i+1) + ": ");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nameRough = keyboard.nextLine();
        String name = nameRough.trim();

      // i have to ask the user to enter the name int he for Last, first and         then rearrange it so this is what thats doing

        String firstName = name.substring(name.indexOf(",")+1);
        String lastName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(","));

        name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    //  name = nameList; 

        System.out.println("");

    // and then here is where i can't figure out how to add name to the           army at i 

        nameList[i] = name;

    }
}
```

Otherwise, you are creating a new list **every iteration** of your loop. You want to create a new **name** every iteration, and then add it to this list that is constant through iterations.

You also had some syntax issues in there, like `nameList` vs `namesList` and not declaring `name` when you first use it.

Comment: It still didn't work, I've tried so many different things. it brought me to the debug window that time tho

Comment: Bonjour!
Enter number of students: 3
Enter name of student # 1: doe,john
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Student.setName(Student.java:47)
 at Grades.main(Grades.java:29)